# Getting error while click on a button using PHP and MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I am getting following  error while clicking on edit button while using PHP and MongoDB.

> Error:

```
category.php:235 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

I am explaining my code below.

> category.php:

```
<?php
 $listdata=$db->kf_category->find();
                                    // print_r(iterator_to_array($listdata));exit;
 $counter = 1;
 foreach($listdata as $v){
 $id=$v['_id'];
$edit=1;
 $del=0;
 echo "<tr>
 <td>".$counter++."</td>
<td>".$v['cat_title']."</td>
<td>
 <select class='form-control' id='status1' name='status1'  style='height:23px; padding:0px;'>
 <option value=''>Select Status</option>
 <option value='1' " . ($v['status']=='1'?'selected':'') . ">Enable</option>
 <option value='0' " . ($v['status']=='0'?'selected':'') . ">Disable</option>
 </select>
 </td>
<td>
<img src='uploads/".$v['image']."' name='pro' border='0' style='width:50px; height:50px; border:#808080 1px solid;' />
 </td>
 <td>
".$v['cat_description']."
 </td>
<td>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green outlinedivnone' data-placement='top' title=''   data-original-title='Edit' onClick='javascript:changeOfActionMenu($id,$edit);'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> </button> 
<button type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger outlinedivnone' data-placement='top' title=''  data-original-title='Delete' onClick='javascript:changeOfActionMenu($id,$del);'><i class='fa fa-times'></i> </button>
</td>
</tr>";
 }
?>
```

When user is clicking on edit icon the above error is coming in the console.Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: can u pin line 235

Comment: @NirpendraPatel : In this line `<button type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green outlinedivnone' data-placement='top' title=''   data-original-title='Edit' onClick='javascript:changeOfActionMenu(572af45be4017ae01200002a,1)'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> </button> ` error is showing in console.

Comment: send a real id like 234 or whatever and 0/1 in place of $edit and del and see if there is any error.

Comment: I checked put like `$id=1,2` .The error is not coming.But when i am using mongoid this type of error is comming.

Comment: you can add function changeOfActionMenu to your code in here and can u rewrite $id=1,2 as a code you actually added like changeOfActionMenu(23,0)

Comment: I have tested doing that and there is no error coming.But in real case i am using the mongoid and in that case this type of error is coming.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111123/discussion-between-satya-and-nirpendra-patel).